# Overide CSS standard component LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I have a simple lightning-vertical-navigation. I am trying to change the text color of the lightning-vertical-navigation-item but the css overide does not seems to works.
Is there a way to do that?

mycomp.html

```
  ...<lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item={selectedItem} onselect={changeHandleAction}>
       <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
           <template for:each={managedContents} for:item="cms">
               <lightning-vertical-navigation-item key={cms.managedContentId} label={cms.title}
                name={cms.managedContentId} > 
               </lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
           </template>
       </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
  </lightning-vertical-navigation>...
```

mycomp.css

```
.slds-nav-vertical__action {
  color: purple !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature of LWC's [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom), which ensures both CSS and Element isolation.

> CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child

You're allowed to modify only what is defined in your component.
Since the element with `slds-nav-vertical__action` class is defined inside the `lightning-vertical-navigation-item` component you have no access and you cannot override its style.

If a component sets a css attribute using [`var()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()), you can override it via [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/#Styling-Hooks-What-Are-Styling-Hooks), but `lightning-vertical-navigation-item` doesn't provide such feature.

You could create your own vertical-navigation-item component from the [blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-navigation/) in order to have full control on its styling.

Comment: Thanks, I do you have any example of vertical-navigation-item from blueprint that implementing the onClick function?

Comment: @RaphaelD no, I'm sorry, but a child component can communicate with its parent via event. In this [documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/events_create_dispatch) there are few examples.

Comment: thanks, well that is maybe not the best option but I finally opted form aura component where I can easily override the css.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behaviour of css encapsulation due to the shadom's DOM. If you want to modify the standard slds css property either you can use [styling hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_styling_hooks).

Since currently salesforce doesn't support styling hooks for `lightning-vertical-navigation-section`, The alternative approach you can go for is

1. Create an external css file with your required css changes which doesn't support by salesforce currently and upload it as a static resource. Use that static resource in your lwc component. Please follow the [link for reference](https://getoncrm.com/how-to-override-css-of-inner-elements-of-lightning-web-component/).
2. Create your own [slds blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-navigation/) for `lightning-vertical-navigation-item`

Any one of the above can solve your requirement.